# Find the distance from the point B to a line l.

Tags: linear-algebra

So we have the point B = (2, 2) and the equation [x,y] = [-1, 2] + t[1, -1].

I know the first thing we need to do is calculate a point on the line, P. I did this by choosing a value for t, and then solving for x and y:

```
t = 1
[x, y] = [-1, 2] + [1, -1] = [0,1] 
P = (0, 1)
```

So now we need to calculate the vector PB:

```
vectorPB = B-P = [2, 2] - [0, 1] = [2, 1]
```

I believe we need a normal vector as well, but I'm not sure how to find this using the vector equation we're given. Ultimately, we want to find the length of the projection of vectorPB onto the normal vector.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Below you find a graph of your line (red colour), the point $B$ (blue colour) and some circles around $B$ to hint on what a useful definition of distance might be.

[image: point and line]

> Ultimately, we want to find the length of the projection of vectorPB
>   onto the normal vector.

That might work as well.

> I believe we need a normal vector as well, ..

The normal vector $n$ would be orthogonal to the direction vector $d$ of the line
$$
n \cdot d = 0
$$
and for convenience one could go for a unit vector.
$$
n \cdot n = 1
$$
From the two possible candidates, we could pick the one which points towards $B$.

> .. but I'm not sure how to
>   find this using the vector equation we're given.

$$
[x,y] = [-1, 2] + t[1, -1]
$$
The line can be characterized by a single point and a direction vector.
What might be the direction vector here?

Comment: Would the direction vector be [-1, 2]?

Comment: No it is not. You see that the line is not parallel to the segment from $[0,0]$ to $[-1,2]$.